# how to set date picker value using CEFsharp browser using vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winforms, datepicker, cefsharp

Using vb.net vs 2019 and latest version of CEFsharp browser, I want to set date picker value dynamically (here From date and To date).
But whenever i run code for click event of submit button, both dates are getting reset.

Below is HTML code for date picker which i am getting through CEF browser:

```
<input id="input-date-start" tabindex="0" aria-label="Start Date" title="Start Date" name="Start Date" data-type="date" required="required" data-bind="datePicker: DateRange.StartDate" data-role="datepicker" type="text" class="k-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="input-date-start_dateview" autocomplete="off" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 100%;" aria-activedescendant="0ff39f75-630d-4162-a40c-2b6bf41f1190_cell_selected">
```

HTML code for button:

```
<button id="btn-dr-update" aria-label="Update Date Range Filter" tabindex="0" class="btnMain btnSize" data-bind="click: DateRange.ApplyClicked">Update</button>
```

I have tried below code to set From and To date picker.

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('input-date-start').value= '" + dtpFromDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "';") 
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('input-date-end_dateview').value= '" & dtpToDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") & "'")
```

But when run below click event dates are getting reset.

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('btn-dr-update').click();")
```

Comment: Without a full example it's not really possible to say. You'll have to look at the rest of the JavaScript source to see what's going on. Open your website in Chrome and use DevTools for debugging,  the problem isn't going to be CefSharp specific.  Focus on getting it working in Chrome first.

Comment: I need to set date picker value. From HTML, it is binding through "data-bind="datePicker: DateRange.StartDate"". But I am new to CEFsharp hence i can not understand how to bind or set value to date picker in background.

Comment: There's nothing CefSharp specific here, investigate in the context of Chrome.  JavaScript natively doesn't have data binding. You'll need to investigate further as to what framework the website is using, knockoutjs, vuejs, angular, something else.